# Move list item in method?

Tags: jquery

I move an item in my list like so:

```
$('.list-item').eq(20).before('.item-to-move');
```

The above works.

When I move the above in to a new method, it fails to work. Why?

For example:

```
p.updatePos = function(){

    $('.list-item').eq(20).before($('.item-to-move'));
}
```

I have logged the above method and it is called. Just for testing purposes I call it like so:

```
$('body').on('click', this.updatePos);
```

Also I have tried this in the method to test I am targeting right:

```
 p.updatePos = function(){

    $('.list-item').hide();
    $('.item-to-move').hide();
}
```

The above works.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a small sample complete with html that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: If you `console.log($('.item-to-move'))`, it will return `[object] [object]`.  That will result in an "undefined" response.  The difference is the `$`.

Comment: What is p, and where do you define it? Shouldn't you use `p` instead of `this` in `$('body').on('click', this.updatePos);`

Answer (score -1):

Here is working version:

```
var p = {
updatePos: function(){
    $('.list-item').eq(5).before($('.item-to-move'));
}
};

$('body').on('click', p.updatePos);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2nw2xczp/

Comment: Thanks but youve changed my method layout. Using your code in my method fails.